# How to return iterations of a list in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started learning classes in Python and I have a problem with them.

I have txt file with the following lines:

```
3 37.5 200

6 36.9 200

9 36.6 100

12 36.6 0
```

When I run the code below, it only prints the first line. However, I would like to retrieve all of the lines. I know you can use `print()`, but is it possible to return?

```
class Meds:

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def meds(self):
        for i in source.readlines():
            data_split = i.strip().split(' ')

            hour = data_split[0]
            temp = data_split[1]
            dose = data_split[2]

            return 'At {0}:00 - he had {1} temp, and took {2} mg of meds'.format(hour, temp, dose)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    source = open('meds.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')

    a = Meds(source)
    print(a.meds())

    source.close()
```

I would really appreciate help on this and would be incredibly happy if you can provide good, **clear** sources explaining classes in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlines()` returns ALL of the lines in the file. You want to use `readline()` instead.

You seem to be iterating through `source` instead of `self.file`. You return from the `meds()` method having only looped over a single line as well. You can also loop directly over the file object. With that in mind, your looping function could look like the following:

```
for line in self.file:
    data_split = i.strip().split(' ')
    hour = data_split[0]
    temp = data_split[1]
    dose = data_split[2]
    yield 'At {0}:00 - he had {1} temp, and took {2} mg of meds'.format(hour, temp, dose)
```

In your code that calls `meds()`, you can use the following:

```
for med in a.meds():
    print(med)
```

For further reading, refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: This is still going to return only one string. The loop will never get past the first iteration.

Comment: I changed the first example code to use `yield` and added usage code for the generator where they call it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Meds` class has two methods, one of which is `__init__`, and the other one is `meds`.

So it's *not* a class but a function in disguise.

Not every programming problem can and should be solved by writing classes.

```
def meds(path):
    with open(path) as medsfile:
        data = [tuple(float(k) for k in ln.split())
                for ln in medsfile if len(ln.strip()) > 0]
    return data
```

Running this on your input data returns a list of tuples:

```
In [4]: meds('meds.txt')
Out[4]: [(3.0, 37.5, 200.0), (6.0, 36.9, 200.0), (9.0, 36.6, 100.0), (12.0, 36.6, 0.0)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get it. But I'm learning classes and my mentor asked me to turn my function into a class.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your code something like there:

```
class Meds:

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def meds(self):
        for i in self.file.readlines():
            data_split = i.strip().split(' ')

            hour = data_split[0]
            temp = data_split[1]
            dose = data_split[2]

            yield 'At {0}:00 - he had {1} temp, and took {2} mg of meds'.format(hour, temp, dose)


source = open('meds.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')

a = Meds(source)
print(list(a.meds()))

source.close()
```

In this case you will use generator [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Comment: the recommended way of handled a file is with the `with` statement